# Automatically generate Gatling scenarios

Tags: java, selenium, gatling

We currently maintain our Gatling simulations manually if a list of REST calls of a page changes. If a developer extends a page with a new call, he has to remember to add that call to Gatling simulation.

How to make sure a simulation is in synch with a web page implementation?

My approach would be to write a Selenium based test and get from a WebDriver a HAR files then parse it to generate a Gatling scenarios. Though possible, this approach feels awkward and I ask myself if there is an established way of solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that the best way to do this is to have a custom Java Class writing the scala files for gatling.

Should take the url and parameters as input and produce a new scala file or just append to an existing scenario.

That should be the best way to do it.

But still it will be better if you directly use the `recorder.sh` that comes with the gatling setup.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure a developer doesn't forget keeping Gatling simulation in synch with web page implementation, you need to ask him if he executed the simulation as a part of his responsibility to test his own changes.
If this is not how your team works maybe a Quality Assistance is needed?